# WCF Service SOAP Object

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a web service in WCF, my contract/interface of my sample method looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INTERFACE
{
    [OperationContract]
    os_consultar oe_consultar(oe_consultar obj_consultar);
}
```

This method generates and XML like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org soap/envelope/" xmlns:wses="http://org.com/wses/"
xmlns:ean="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07 Ean.PaymentGateway.Bank.BankInterfaceEntity">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <wses:oe_consultar>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <wses:obj_consultar>
        <cod1>?</cod1>
        <cod2>?</cod2>
     </wses:obj_consultar>
  </wses:oe_consultar>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to know if it is possible to generate the xml this way:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org soap/envelope/" xmlns:wses="http://org.com/wses/"
xmlns:ean="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07 Ean.PaymentGateway.Bank.BankInterfaceEntity">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <wses:oe_consultar>
    <cod1>?</cod1>
    <cod2>?</cod2>
  </wses:oe_consultar>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INTERFACE
{
    [OperationContract]
    void oe_consultar(cod1 string, cod2 string);
}
```

Comment: with that apear
    <wses:oe_consultar>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <wses:oe_consultar>
    <cod1>?</cod1>'

Comment: nope i need  <wses:oe_consultar> <cod1>?</cod1> without the duplicate  <wses:oe_consultar>

Comment: i obtain the same  <wses:oe_consultar> <!--Optional:--> <wses:oe_consultar> <cod1>?</cod1>

Comment: have you tried passing parameters instead the object itself? look at my code

Comment: yes but each element comes with the prefix like this
<wses:oe_consultar> <wses:cod1>?</wses:cod1>
and i need it without the prefix there are any way to delet the prefix on each element and not in the root?

Comment: Carlos, I think what you want is not possible, <wses:oe_consultar> is the method name and <!--Optional:--><wses:obj_consultar> is the param, so even if it is a class or a single string it will have wses

Comment: So there is no way to have the metod name <wses:oe_consultar> and the params <cod1>?</cod1>

Comment: Once I tried to generate my own xml but it did not work, so better to find another approach.

Comment: That's a bad new because in java it can be developed like i nedd but the user uses wcf

Comment: SOAP promisses a standart, but I had same kind of issues with Java and PHP, look at this open question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004968/soap-customtextmessageencoder